# Unhandled Exception: Invalid argument: Instance of 'CartItemModel'

Tags: flutter, dart

i am working on a store application and after the user places an order, i will like to store that order details in the firebase firestore. the function for carrying out that call after the button is pressed is this

```
 addOrderDetails() {
final user  = Provider.of<UserProvider>(context, listen: false);
writeOrderDetailsForUser({
  "userId" : user.user.uid,
  "description" : "Cash on delivery",
  "status" : "pending",
  "createdAt": DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch.toString(),
  "totalPrice" : user.userModel.totalCartPrice,
   "cart" : user.userModel.cart,
  "address" : widget.addressId,
  "phone" : user.userModel.phone,
 }).whenComplete(() async {
  for (CartItemModel cartItem in user.userModel.cart){
    bool value = await user.removeFromCart(cartItem: cartItem);
    if(value) {
      user.reloadUserModel();
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text("Item has been successfully removed from cart"),));
    }else {
      print(
        "item has not been removed from cart please try again"
      );
    }
  }
  ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
    content: Text(
        "Your order has been successfully created, please we will call you in a few minutes to confirm your order"),));
});
changeScreenReplacement(context, NavigationController());
```

}

```
Future writeOrderDetailsForUser(Map<String, dynamic> data) async
  {
    await EcommerceApp.firestore
        .collection(EcommerceApp.collectionOrders)
        .document(EcommerceApp.sharedPreferences.getString(EcommerceApp.userUID) + data['createdAt'])
        .setData(data);
  }
}
```

However i am getting this error anytime i make the function call

I/flutter (24853): cart items are: Instance of 'CartItemModel'
E/flutter (24853): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(199)] **Unhandled Exception: Invalid argument: Instance of 'CartItemModel'**
E/flutter (24853): #0      StandardMessageCodec.writeValue (package:flutter/src/services/message_codecs.dart:419:7)
E/flutter (24853): #1      FirestoreMessageCodec.writeValue (package:cloud_firestore_platform_interface/src/method_channel/utils/firestore_message_codec.dart:83:13)
E/flutter (24853): #2      StandardMessageCodec.writeValue (package:flutter/src/services/message_codecs.dart:409:9)
E/flutter (24853): #3      FirestoreMessageCodec.writeValue (package:cloud_firestore_platform_interface/src/method_channel/utils/firestore_message_codec.dart:83:13)
E/flutter (24853): #4      StandardMessageCodec.writeValue. (package:flutter/src/services/message_codecs.dart:416:9)
E/flutter (24853): #5      _LinkedHashMapMixin.forEach (dart:collection-patch/compact_hash.dart:397:8)
E/flutter (24853): #6      StandardMessageCodec.writeValue (package:flutter/src/services/message_codecs.dart:414:13)
E/flutter (24853): #7      FirestoreMessageCodec.writeValue (package:cloud_firestore_platform_interface/src/method_channel/utils/firestore_message_codec.dart:83:13)
E/flutter (24853): #8      StandardMessageCodec.writeValue. (package:flutter/src/services/message_codecs.dart:416:9)
E/flutter (24853): #9      _LinkedHashMapMixin.forEach (dart:collection-patch/compact_hash.dart:397:8)
E/flutter (24853): #10     StandardMessageCodec.writeValue (package:flutter/src/services/message_codecs.dart:414:13)
E/flutter (24853): #11     FirestoreMessageCodec.writeValue (package:cloud_firestore_platform_interface/src/method_channel/utils/firestore_message_codec.dart:83:13)
E/flutter (24853): #12     StandardMethodCodec.encodeMethodCall (package:flutter/src/services/message_codecs.dart:551:18)
E/flutter (24853): #13     MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:150:13)
E/flutter (24853): #14     MethodChannel.invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:331:12)
E/flutter (24853): #15     MethodChannelDocumentReference.setData (package:cloud_firestore_platform_interface/src/method_channel/method_channel_document_reference.dart:28:43)
E/flutter (24853): #16     DocumentReference.setData (package:cloud_firestore/src/document_reference.dart:48:22)
E/flutter (24853): #17     _PaymentPageState.writeOrderDetailsForUser (package:maen/screens/placeOrderPayment.dart:349:10)
E/flutter (24853): #18     _PaymentPageState.addOrderDetails (package:maen/screens/placeOrderPayment.dart:316:5)
E/flutter (24853): #19     _PaymentPageState.build. (package:maen/screens/placeOrderPayment.dart:297:17)

Comment: Hi, if you can improve your question will be more easy to help you, please read the guidelines https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: It is pretty impossible for anybody to help you with this. You are just showing a function call (_orderServices.createOrder), but how is anybody except for you gonna know what that function does?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: pleasse i just edited the question, is it better now?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is caused because of this line

```
 "cart" : user.userModel.cart,
```

Seems like your user.userModel.cart is the List of CartItemModel,

To overcome this you'll have to serialize this and then add to the database, because database doesn't know anything about CartItemModel,

Do something like this:

```
"cart" : user.userModel.cart.map((e)=>e.toJson()).toList();
```

In **CartItemModel** define the **toJson** function

As the details is less, I assume CartItemModel has fields like `id , name and price`

```
Map toJson() => {
        'id': id,
        'name': name,
        'price' : price
      };
```

This should solve your problem